# What are general conditions for a sequence created by iterating a function to satisfy the hypotheses of the Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Most textbook problems I see on the Monotone Convergence Theorem involve a sequence defined recursively by iterating some function, i.e.

$x_0 = a$ and $x_{i} = f(x_{i-1})$ for $i \geq 1$.

For instance, a textbook I am looking at now has:

$x_0 = 3$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{4-x}$

$x_0 = \sqrt{2}$ and $f(x) = \sqrt{2x}$

$x_0 = 2$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x + \frac{2}{x})$.

In each case, you can show that the sequence formed by iterating $f$ at the starting value stays bounded, and then the monotonicity is a consequence of $f$ having the property that its output exceeds the input (or vice-versa, for a decreasing sequence), at least over the interval where the sequence terms lie.

Are there general conditions for an initial point and function to lead to a sequence that satisfies the hypotheses of the MCT? I am interested especially in producing lots of examples without too much effort.